# How can size of a structure be a non-multiple of 4?

Tags: c, struct, sizeof

I'm new to structures and was learning how to find the size of structures. I'm aware of how padding comes in to play in order to properly align the memory. From what I've understood, the alignment is done so that the size in memory comes out to be a multiple of 4.
I tried the following piece of code on GCC.

```
struct books{
  short int number;
  char name[3];
}book;
printf("%lu",sizeof(book));
```

Initially I had thought that the short int would occupy 2 bytes, followed by the character array starting at the third memory location from the beginning. The character array then would need a padding of 3 bytes which would give a size of 8. Something like this, where each word represents a byte in memory.

short short char char

char padding padding padding

However on running it gives a size of 6, which confuses me.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: The compiler is free to pad the structure members the way it wishes. In your case it looks like it only cares that it would be multiple of the largest struct element.

Comment: The `struct` is aligned to the element within it with the largest alignment. In this case `short` is aligned to 2 bytes and `char` only to 1 byte, so the struct is aligned to 2 bytes. You have a 2-byte `short`, 0 bytes of alignment padding, 3 bytes of `char`, and then 1 byte of alignment padding at the end of the struct to make it a multiple of its alignment. 2+0+3+1=6.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Great question.

Comment: While each element has to be aligned according to its size, the **start** of the struct has to be aligned to the **largest** struct element. I.e. if you have `uint8_t a; uint16_t b; uint64_t c; uint8_t d;`, there will be a 1B padding after `a`, 7B padding after `b`, no padding after `c`, and then again 7B padding after `d`. The padding at the end is needed to ensure that `c` will be aligned when you have an array of structs.

Answer (score 4):

Generally, **padding is inserted to allow for aligned access of the internal elements of the structure**, not to allow the entire structure to be a size of multiple words.  Alignment is a compiler implementation issue, not a requirement of the C standard.

So, the char elements which are 3 bytes in length, need no alignment because they are byte elements.

It is preferred, though not required, that the short element needs to be aligned on a short boundary -- which means an even address.  By aligning it on a short boundary, the compiler can issue a single load short instruction rather than having to load a word, mask, and then shift.

In this case, the padding is probably, but not necessarily, happening at the end rather than in the middle.  You will have to write code to dump the address of the elements to determine where padding is taking place.

**EDIT:** . As @Euguen Sh mentions, even if you discover the padding scheme that the compiler is using for the structure, the compiler could modify that in a different version of the compiler.

It is unwise to count on the padding scheme of the compiler.  There are always methods to access the elements in such a way that you do not guess at alignments.

The sizeof() operator is used to allow you to see how much memory is used AND to know how much will be added to a ptr to the structure if that pointer is incremented by 1 (ptr++).

**EDIT 2, Packing**: Structures may be packed to prevent padding using the `__packed__` attribute.  When designing a structure, it is wise to use elements that naturally pack.  This is especially important when sending data over a communications link.  A carefully designed structure avoids the need for padding in the middle of the strucuture.  A poorly designed structure which is then compiled with the `__packed__` attribute may have internal elements that are not naturally aligned.  One might do this to ensure that the structure will transmit across a wire as it was originally designed.  This type of effort has diminished with the introduction of JSON for transmission of data over a wire.

Comment: Note, that the padding could change if one is defining an *array* of such a structures.

Comment: @EugeneSh. No, it can’t: array indexing is defined via pointer offset in multiples of `sizeof (ElementType)`. That would break if the size were variable. In other words, `sizeof (T[N]) == sizeof (T) * N`.

Comment: @KonradRudolph No, I didn't mean it can change within the same build. I am saying that the compiler might decide of how it is sizing the type based on it's usage (consistently of course). I believe I saw this before.

Comment: @EugeneSh.: That cannot happen. First, if you declared an object in a header and used it in one source file in an array and in another source file as a single object, the object has to have the same size in both source files. The compiler could not give it a different size because it was used in an array. Second, `sizeof` gives the total number of bytes used for an object, including trailing padding (C 2018 6.5.3.4 4). Third, an array is a contiguously allocated set of objects, so it cannot have its own internal padding; the size of its element type must include the padding they need.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I am trying to reproduce the effect I believe I saw before.. but looks like I am unable to. The only thing I see that the `__attribute__((aligned(..)))` is changing the size of a structure to accommodate the use-case of it being a part of a composite type.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <stdalign.h>
#include <assert.h>
```

The size of a struct is always divisible by the maximum alignment of the members (which must be a power of two). 
If you have a struct with `char` and `short` the alignment is 2, because the alignment of `short` is two, if you have a struct, only out of `char`s it has an alignment of 1.

There are multiple ways to manipulate the alignment:

```
alignas(4) char[4]; // this can hold 32-bit ints
```

This is nonstandart, but available in most compilers (GCC, Clang, ...):

```
struct A {
    char a;
    short b;
};

struct __attribute__((packed)) B {
    char a;
    short b;
};

static_assert(sizeof(struct A) == 4);
static_assert(alignof(struct A) == 2);

static_assert(sizeof(struct B) == 3);
static_assert(alignof(struct B) == 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually compilers follow ABI of the target architecture. 
It defines alignments of structures and primitive datatypes. And that affects to needed padding and sizes of structures. Because alignment is multiple of 4 in many architectures, size of structures are too.

Compilers may offer some attributes/options for changing alignments more or less directly.

For example gcc and clang offers: `__attribute__ ((packed))`